# Is there anything wrong with using this system?

Tags: java, software-design

When building software I often find that I need to give instances around a lot so that they can refer to each other's non-static members. Instead of passing around large numbers of objects I could create a class (in Java) like the following:

```
public class Handler {

    private HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(String key, Object value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object get(String key, Object value) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

You could then pass this class around and have every object that uses it add themselves into the handler so that you could share things between instances quite easily. You could even make a "static" version of this class and add commonly accessed variables e.g. screen dimensions.

I feel like using the above would fairly bad to do on a software design level. Is there anything "wrong" with this?

Comment: The main problem with it is that you lose type information: you don't know if any given instance of `Handler` has a given key, and you don't know if the value associated with the key is of a given type.

Comment: It also becomes very easy to accidentally overwrite an existing entry by inadvertently reusing an existing key, especially as the map gets bigger. Good luck tracking those bugs down. You may also find that you run into memory issues further down the line because you're keeping objects alive that would ordinarily have died and been garbage collected long ago.

Comment: This can be assimilated to a Registry pattern.

Comment: This violates *a ton* of good design practices. Passing around some is fairly normal but their number should automatically be limited in good designs: if you adhere to the single responsibility principle then each individual part of your program only needs to know about a few other objects, definitely not “large numbers”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the approach you describe is that you cannot enforce and/or guarantee that a given key has a value of a specific type. What this means is that you would then need to do casting of objects to get them back (and hope that the casting does not fail...)

If you need to share items around, consider having a repository, once for each object type. You could then query this repository for items and you would be able to modify them as needed.

Keep in mind that this can cause concurrency issues, so build your repositories accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with it is that you lose type information: you don't know if any given instance of `Handler` has a given key, and you don't know if the value associated with the key is of a given type.

This isn't necessarily a problem - you just have to put in a lot more effort to ensure that you put the right things in, and validate that you get the things you expect out of it.

You are better off defining a custom class for each purpose, with semantically-meaningful fields:

```
class Specific {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private List<String> friends;

  // Define getters etc.
}
```

Get your IDE to generate the boilerplate code for you. Or look into something like [Google's AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) which generates the classes for you at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency issues for example.
It would also suppose that you can identify all instances of the object you need with the keys.

Comment: Concurrency trouble is not a design issue, rather an implementation problem. You can use a ConcurrentHashMap.